# Referencing resource dictionaries from an external project

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to make a resource dictionary in a separate library (framework) project and then reference it in another library project? In this separate project I have a UserControl that wants to use it.

This is my how my solution is set up.

[image]

SharedProject has the resource dictionaries and I reference it in my Plugin project. I then export my Plugin library into MainProject and have it displaying my views from Plugin.

I have all this working... except for my dictionaries. I have tried referencing my dictionaries in each of my views

```
<UserControl.Resources>  
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="dictionary">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/InternalShared;component/Resources/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/InternalShared;component/Resources/Dictionary2.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

But when I try to reference an existing style...

```
<Button     Command="{Binding CommandOpenFile}"
            Style="{DynamicResource GenericButtonStyle}" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
            Content="Restore Window" 
            Height="Auto" />
```

But I get *The resource "GenericButtonStyle" could not be resolved*. This is happening everywhere I try refernce the style in any of my dictionaries. I don't know why.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Is there somewhere else I need to set this declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain an external WPF UI library that is used by many different solutions.

- Make sure InternalShared is a WPF DLL
- Merge in your external resources into the `App.xaml` of your main WPF app instead

For instance, applications using my resources merge them in like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/InternalShared;component/Resources/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the asist. I didn't know that simply setting your dictionaries in App.xaml allows all the projects to simply reference their elements like that.